# JSDOM : Uncaught TypeError: window.document.getElementByTagName is not a function

Tags: jsdom

I am using the JSDOM library for testing my application. Below is my code which I use to test my index.html file

```
 import { expect } from 'chai';
import jsdom from 'jsdom';
import fs from 'fs';

describe('Our first test', () => {
  it('should pass', () => {
    expect(true).to.equal(true);
  });
});

describe('index.html', () => {
  it('should have h1 that says Users', (done) => {
    const index = fs.readFileSync('./src/index.html', "utf-8");
    jsdom.env(index, function (err, window) {
      const h1 = window.document.getElementsByTagName('h1')[0];
      expect(h1.innerHTML).to.equal("Hello World!..");
      done();
      window.close();
    });
  })
})
```

When I run npm test command I am getting the below error

> Uncaught TypeError: window.document.getElementByTagName is not a function

could anyone please assist me

Comment: Have you tried using jsdom.window.document.getElementsByTagName ?

Comment: @KuldeepDubey no let me try this

Comment: @KuldeepDubey now i am getting this error Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'document' of undefined